# Should I use "did" in the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

> She had been more professional than he had expected, quickly dropping
>   the subject. Nor (did) she ask, "Why did you go there?"

Do I need the *did*? Why or why not? (Or maybe I'm using the wrong phrase?)

Comment: Your previous sentence is in the past perfect, if you want to continue in this tense then you'd write "Nor had she asked," if you chose to transition into the simple past "Nor did she ask," is correct.

Comment: @Jakub: Your comment answers the question, and so would be better as an answer (with citations/dictionary references, if possible).